# (WPF) How to change button image background in listBox with buttons in each line ?

Tags: c#, wpf, listbox, datatemplate

i have listbox, and the data template is button :

```
 <ListBox  x:Name="lbname" ItemsSource="{Binding myCollection}">        
        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Button x:Name="btnname" Content="{Binding name}" Click="btnname_Click">
                    <Button.Background>
                        <ImageBrush ImageSource="/myApplication;component/images/buttons/normal.png"/>
                    </Button.Background>
                </Button>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ListBox>
```

i have two image backgroud for this listBox image (normal.png for normal mode, click.png for selected item in listBox)

The listBox view items in list of buttons, the button image background is normally normal.png

my question is how to change the button image background to click.png for selected one and the old selected button retrieve to normal.png

How to change image background for selected item in listBox with buttons in each line ?

hope this clear, please i spend about one day about this issue
can any one help

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't tested it, but you need some code that looks like this:

```
<ListBox x:Name="lbname" ItemsSource="{Binding myCollection}">
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Button x:Name="btnname" Click="btnname_Click">
                <Grid>
                    <Image>
                        <Image.Style>
                            <Style>
                                <Setter Property="Image.Source" 
Value="/myApplication;component/images/buttons/normal.png" />
                                <Style.Triggers>
                                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsSelected, 
RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type ListBoxItem}}}" 
Value="True">
                                        <Setter Property="Image.Source" 
Value="/myApplication;component/images/buttons/click.png" />
                                    </DataTrigger>
                                </Style.Triggers>
                            </Style>
                        </Image.Style>
                    </Image>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding name}" HorizontalAlignment="Center" 
VerticalAlignment="Center" />
                </Grid>
            </Button>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

The idea is to bind directly to the `IsSelected` property of the `ListBoxItem` object. This is done using a `RelativeSource` binding. However, I'm guessing that this code doesn't do what you want... I suggest that you might want to use a `ToggleButton` instead... something like this:

```
<ListBox x:Name="lbname" ItemsSource="{Binding myCollection}">
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <ToggleButton x:Name="btnname" Click="btnname_Click" IsChecked="{Binding 
IsSelected, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type 
ListBoxItem}}}">
                <Grid>
                    <Image>
                        <Image.Style>
                            <Style>
                                <Setter Property="Image.Source" 
Value="/myApplication;component/images/buttons/normal.png" />
                                <Style.Triggers>
                                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsSelected, 
RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type ListBoxItem}}}" 
Value="True">
                                        <Setter Property="Image.Source" 
Value="/myApplication;component/images/buttons/click.png" />
                                    </DataTrigger>
                                </Style.Triggers>
                            </Style>
                        </Image.Style>
                    </Image>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding name}" HorizontalAlignment="Center" 
VerticalAlignment="Center" />
                </Grid>
            </ToggleButton>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

Comment: Thanks Sheridan, it's work with some changes, i got the idea and with using the toggle button it's solved, Thanks so much :)

Answer (score 0):

if you are using MVVM then make a property in viewModel and bind this to ImageBrush as ImageSource,
when you are selecting value in ListView then get selected record and change image path of this property.

Answer (score 0):

Try using Togglebutton instead of button.Use a trigger to check when the IsChecked property of the toggleButton changes. And based on that change your image.

Comment: -1 Why would you add an answer *after* a correct answer had been selected and just provide *some small part* of information from that correct answer in your answer?... utterly pointless.

Comment: I didnot see the answer had been given.I went on to receive a call opening this tab and no answer were given then.And I posted the answer after coming back

Comment: +1 Fair enough. In future, it *might* be an idea to update the page just before you post an answer? Note: I had to edit your answer (I simply added a space) before I was allowed to remove the -1.